# How to use mailchimp for Magento 2.4 Customer Registration mails

Tags: magento2.4, customer-account, mailchimp

Im using Magento 2.4 and all order confirmation mails are triggered from mailchimp.How to trigger Customer Registration Email from Mailchimp